# Element not updated with calculated value in Angular.js v 1.0.7

Tags: angularjs

When I load a page to display items prices, before the prices are calculated in the controller the page displays "null" in the price for a while (maybe 1 sec). How can I avoid this? I thought this is the purpose of ng-init, is it right?

When I use it, I get my items initialized to 0. This is ok. However, when the value is calculated the price is not updated.

Example:

```
<div class="text-right custom_block_field" ng-show="booking.duration == 0" ng-init="itemSelected.convertedPrice = 0">{{(itemSelected.convertedPrice)}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-init is not for that, it is basically used to call a method or some initialization of the values

```
<div class="text-right custom_block_field" 
     ng-show="booking.duration == 0" 
     ng-bind="itemSelected.convertedPrice"></div>
```

Or use the [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) with parent element

Answer (score 0):

ng-cloack is the best way. It'll mask a value until it's ready.

```
<div ng-cloak>
    //whatever your app code is
</div>
```